# im not able to save the screen shot from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

kindly help me im not able to save the screen shot on the desired folder the code is running however the screen shot is not saving on the path please help

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

# part of the screen
time.sleep(2)
#(left_x, top_y, right_x, bottom_y).
#screen shot of the required place 
path= (r'C:\Users\RTambe00000\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\Pyautogui\photos')
im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(900,1000,1200,1100))
im= im.resize((224,224),Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save(path+'.jpeg')
```

Comment: what do you mean by not saving? What is the issue?

Comment: You're saving the image to `Pyautogui\photos.jpeg` - were you intending `photos` to be a directory?

Comment: i mean to say that it was not saving in my path which i gave

Comment: i solved my issue by used this code im.save(path+'\\'+'ss.png')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i was able to solve it and got my code working

```
def takescreenshot():
    #image_name= f"im-{str(datetime.datetime.now())}"
    path= (r'C:\Users\RTamb\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\Pyautogui\photos\{image_name}.png')
    im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(955,1032,1130,1050))
    
    im.save(path)

takescreenshot()
```